# Android Animation only works the first time

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, alpha

I am testing an app that I am in the process of making. When the application starts up, the splash screen is supposed to do a fade in/fade out animation into the login screen. When the application starts up FOR THE FIRST TIME, the animation works fine. But once I clear the application from task manager and restart it, the animation doesn't appear and it goes straight to the login screen with no animation occuring. Attached are the parts of the code dealing with the animation. If any other piece of the code is needed I will provide that as well. I just want it so the animation runs EVERY TIME the application runs.

SplashScreen.java

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);



    Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                sleep(3000);
            }catch(InterruptedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            finally{
                Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
            }
        }
    };
    timerThread.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    finish();
}

}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    // Set up the login form.
    registerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    registerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);

            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out);

        }
    });
```

fade_in.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0"
android:duration="2000" />
```

fade_out.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:duration="2000" />
```

activity_login.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.drinkuprewards.julian.drinkuprewards.LoginActivity"
android:background="#97007C">

<!-- Login progress -->

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="false">

</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:src="@drawable/logosm"
        android:contentDescription="@string/mainlogo" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_email"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:background="#fef500"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spacer" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
        android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
        android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:autoText="false"
        android:background="#fef500"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/action_register"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#fef500"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

    <Button
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="#fef500"
        android:onClick="Register"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="@string/version_number"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

do not use `sleep()` to delay starting another activity. You can do what you want like

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
       Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
        finish();
    }
}, 3000);
```

this should work.

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly! I appreciate this.